# C-Comparison with multiple variables in a if statement

Tags: c, comparison, operators

Hi so i'm new at coding in C and i'd like to know how to compare several variables.
Cause my if statement is only working for the first variable and ignore the ||.

```
scanf("%d %c %d", &nbsaisi, &op, &nbsaisi2); 
if((op != multi) || (op != plus) || (op != moins) || (op!= divi))
   {  
    printf("You haven't entered a valid operator.\n"); 
    exit(1); 
   }
```

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: `&&` = and
`||` = or . Read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_logical_operators.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter inside the if block only if all the conditions are met, so in your case your conditions should be in `&&` and not in `||`

```
if((op != multi) && (op != plus) && (op != moins) && (op!= divi))
   {  
    printf("You haven't entered a valid operator.\n"); 
    exit(1); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use && instead of ||